# The existence of $T$-ultrafilters in ZFC

Tags: set-theory, forcing, ultrafilters, independence-results

Looking at this [MO-problem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/351827/61536), my collegue Igor Protasov suggested to ask on Mathoverflow his old question on $T$-ultrafilters hoping that somebody on MO can solve it.

First I recall the necessary definitions.

By a *partition* of $\omega$ we understand a cover of $\omega$ by pairwise disjoint nonempty subsets. A partition $\mathcal P$ is called *finitary* if $\sup_{P\in\mathcal P}|P|$ is finite.

Let $\mathfrak P$ is a family of partitions of $\omega$. An infinite subset $T\subset\omega$ is called *$\mathfrak P$-thin* if for any partition $\mathcal P\in\mathfrak P$ there exists a finite set $F\subset T$ such that for any $P\in\mathcal P$ the intersection $P\cap (T\setminus F)$ contains at most one point.

A free ultrafilter $\mathcal U$ on $\omega$ is called a *$T$-point* (or else a *$T$-ultrafilter*) if for any countable family $\mathfrak P$ of finitary partitions of $\omega$ there exists a $\mathfrak P$-thin set $T\in\mathcal U$.

[Petrenko and Protasov](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ndjfl/1336586239)  proved that a free ultrafilter is a $T$-point whenever it is a $P$-point or a $Q$-point.

It is well-known that there are models of ZFC containing no $P$-points and there are models of ZFC containing no $Q$-points. But it is not known yet if there exists a model of ZFC containing neither $P$-points nor $Q$-points. That is why the following question of Protasov is interesting (and non-trivial).

> **Problem 1.** Can the existence of $T$-points be proved in ZFC?
>
> **Problem 2.** Are Kunen's OK-points $T$-points?